# Gzip or tars logs that are older than 7 days

Tags: linux, bash

Need to create a single script that would Gzip or tars logs that are older than 7 days in multiple (3) paths /home/temp, home/logs, then confirm this one is over 50% capacity home/var/lib/mongo. This is what I got so far but I can't think of how to combine these:

```
find . -mtime +7 -print -exec gzip {} \; for all 3 but them

find /tmp/log/ -mtime +7 -type f -exec sh -c \
```

'tar -czvPf /tmp/older_log_$(basename $0)_$(date +%F).tar.gz $0' {} ;

```
# create a single tar file for each archive +7 days old on one mount
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Look at [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate): https://www.tecmint.com/install-logrotate-to-manage-log-rotation-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correclty, you would like to archive multiple old logs in one tar files:

```
find /tmp/log /home/temp /home/logs -mtime +7 -type f \
| xargs tar -czf /tmp/older_log_$(date +%F).tar.gz --remove-files
```

For easy reading I put it on two lines.

1. It searches for all files you want to archive
2. Pass the found files as arguments to the tar archive (using xargs)
3. tar will make the new archive and add all the files
4. additionally tar will remove the original files with the last oiption (from GNU tar)